# how do i reconfigure Boost?

Tags: unix, boost, shared-ptr, configure

i am currently using boost shared memory api and need to write to /tmp instead of /var by disabling BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS in interprocess/detail/workaround.hpp.

I have undef the flag but my program still writes to /var instead of /tmp. Is there an additional step i am missing to this?